# C++ <<operator overloading with same type

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I'm writing a method to print some spaces in `std::cout`, I know there are other ways using the standard library to achieve the same objective. Anyway, I used a `typedef` to store the number of spaces and an overloading of the `<<` operator. But my overloading isn't called at all because my `typedef` is interpreted as an unsigned int.

So how can I tell to the compiler to call my function instead ?

```
class MyClass {
private: 
  typedef unsigned int space_type;

public: 
  std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& _os, space_type _n_spaces) {
    for (int _C = 0; _C < _n_spaces; _C++) 
      _os << " ";
    return _os;
  }

  void PrintNumbers(char _a, char _b) {
    space_type spaces = 5;
    std::cout << _a << spaces << _b << std::endl;
  }
}

int main () {
  MyClass class_instance;
  class_instance.PrintNumbers('K', 'X');

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

This is the expected output:

```
K     X
```

This is the output I obtain:

```
K5X  // 5 is interpreted as an unsigned int, so my overloaded function 
     // isn't called, instead is called the std overloading with unsigned int
```

Comment: Typedef doesn't create new type, it just creates alias of existing type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're defining `space_type` as an *alias* (i.e. typedef) and not a type, it is not distinguishable from `int`, and the compiler will issue an error if you attempted to overload `operator(std::ostream&, int)`.

But what you're doing is defining a class member:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& _os, space_type _n_spaces)
```

When you define operators as class members, the first argument to the operator is (implicitly) an instance of the class. So in principle, that could only be called with:

```
MyClass m;
m << ???
```

But here is a problem: an operator function called using infix notation can only have two parameters, and in the case of a member operator function, the first argument is implicit. `m << x` can only be implemented by `MyClass::operator<<(decltype(x))`.

In short, you can only implement this with a non-member `operator<<` and the second argument to that overload must be a user type. So the following will work fine:

```
struct space_t {
   unsigned x;
   space_t(unsigned x) : x(x) {}
   operator unsigned() const { return x; }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, space_t n) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i) os << " ";
  return os;
}
```

See it on [ideeone](http://ideone.com/VK5q3U)

Comment: But if i replace the typedef with a struct, the overloaded function inside a class work fine.

Comment: @Michele: Do you mean this: http://ideone.com/1y9Akx (But that's gives the expected compilation error).

Answer (score 2):

Typedef doesn't create new type, it just creates alias of existing type. Possbile you could use something like this:

```
struct SpaceType {
    int space_cnt;
};
...
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& _os, SpaceType _n_spaces) {
    for (int _C = 0; _C < _n_spaces.space_cnt; _C++) 
      _os << " ";
    return _os;
  }
...  
SpaceType spaces = { 5 };
std::cout << _a << spaces << _b << std::endl;
```

Comment: I knew that solution but i would like to avoid usage of struct for this purpose

Comment: @Michele: Why? There's no real cost.

Comment: Because i feel i'm wasting lines of codes writing down a struct and instances just for a bunch of spaces. Anyway if there aren't solution it's okay.